# combobox and textbox item not displaying properly on datagrid

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox, ms-access-2013

my code is this for the button

```
try
{
   con.Open();
   OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into slogin values('" + todayDay + "','" + txtDate.Text + "','" + cboStudentNo + "','" + txtLastName + "','" + txtFirstName + "','" + cboComputerNo + "')", con);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   // OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("update into Computer set Status='Occupied'where PcNumber='" + cboComputerNo.Text + "'", con);
   // cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
   con.Close();
   Computer();
   Student();
   dgv();
   time();
   MessageBox.Show("login success");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

- computer() is for computer vacancy
- student() is for student data
- dgv() loads table
- i get this error when i press the button
- 1.System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox, Items.Count: 12 / studentID
- 2.System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: Llenares / lastname
- 3.System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: Nette / firstname
- 4.System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox, Items.Count: 10 / pcnumber
- the code for date and time is working.
- i am using c# and msAccess for my database

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you showed us the code of Computer(),student() dgv() and time().

Comment: use txtLastName.Text instead of txtLastName , also cboStudentNo.Text

Comment: damn i forgot to add text , the next time i see that message i will know what to do thnx houssam

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into slogin values('" + todayDay.Text + "','" + txtDate.Text + "','" + cboStudentNo.SelectedValue.Text + "','" + txtLastName.Text + "','" + txtFirstName.Text + "','" + cboComputerNo.SelectedValue.Text + "')", con);``
```

Even your are not asking, you should use parameters for security reasons insted plain text: 
[Using Parameters in Sql Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/using-parameters-in-sql-statements)